# Slider step in WP7

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

How I can get step (0.5) in slider control in WP7?

It can change values like 0.5-1.0-1.5-2.0...

[image: slider wp7]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `SmallChange` and `LargeChange` properties to `0.5`. Like this:

```
<Slider x:Name="Slider" SmallChange="0.5" LargeChange="0.5" />
```

In addition, you can handle the `ValueChanged` event like so:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Slider.Value = Math.Round(e.NewValue * 2) /2;
}
```

Comment: I've already set, but I can get values like "1.29034302490", "3.329949"

Comment: @wsevendays I've edited my post to include additional details.